# control requestedOrientation inside of TabChildActivity

Tags: java, android, exception, orientation, android-fragments

I have an TabActivity which hosts several Activitys. Inside 1 Activity I have to set the orientation to `landscape` (a camera Activity which wount work in portrait mode on Android 2.1). If I call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` inside my Child, nothing seems to happen. I thought that I could try to set the orientation of Activity through its Parent (TabActivity) like this:

```
//DefaultGroup is an FragmentActivity
public class ChildActivity extends DefaultGroup{

TabActivity mParent;
int previosOrientation;


public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (getParent() instanceof TabActivity){
        mParent = (TabActivity)getParent();
        previosOrientation = mParent.getRequestedOrientation();
        mParent.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
        //request to DefaultGroup to set CameraFragment as ContentView
        // 0=id, null= Bundle, false=addToBackStack
    startFragment(0, null, false);
}


public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mParent != null){
        mParent.setRequestedOrientation(previosOrientation);
    }
}

@Override
public DefaultFragment getFragment(int fragment, Bundle args) {
    return new CameraFragment();
}

}
```

which works well if the Activity gets created. After I click on another TabButton the orientation is set back to whatever it was before. But if I come back to that Tab I get a forceClose containing this LogCat-Stacktrace:

> 01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {de.my.namespace.ChildActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:178)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:329)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:540)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1242)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1253)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:535)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:519)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at de.my.namespace.activity.DefaultGroup.addFragment(DefaultGroup.java:162)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at de.my.namespace.activity.DefaultGroup.startFragment(DefaultGroup.java:145)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at de.my.namespace.activity.ChildaActivity.onResume(AugmentedRealityActivity.java:26)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
>   01-27 16:19:21.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30134):    ... 17 more

so baically my question is: How can I force the orientation of my Child/TabActivity inside one special child while setting these settings back If I leave that special Child?